# Is a parameter-independent support sufficient to belong to an exponential family?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, exponential-family

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family#Classical_estimation:_sufficiency) (emphasis mine):

> As a counterexample if these conditions are relaxed, the family of uniform distributions (either discrete or continuous, with either or both bounds unknown) has a sufficient statistic, namely the sample maximum, sample minimum, and sample size, **but does not form an exponential family, as the domain varies with the parameters.**

Does this mean that if the support (not domain) of a particular distribution does not vary with its parameters, then it is a member of an exponential family of distributions?

Comment: no this is not true, see the Student's t family.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NO**

A $t_{\nu}$ distribution has support on all of $\mathbb R$, no matter $\nu$.

[However, $t_{\nu}$ does not have a moment-generating function, which is a requirement to be an exponential family.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/444470/247274)